# python class namespace and init function

Tags: python, class, namespaces, scope

```
class Complex:
     realpart,imagpart=0,0
     def __init__(self):
          self.r = Complex.realpart
          self.i = Complex.imagpart

x = Complex()
```

the above code works, x.r,x.i = (0,0), but when the class name is big, Class_name.Data_member way of accessing class data looks very redundant, is there any way to improve the class scoping, so I don't have to use Complex.imagpart? just use self.r = realpart?

Comment: 1. No, this is not Visual Basic. 2. Why not use the builtin `complex` type?

Comment: Propably not possible (without vastly modifying the language, which you won't achive anyway) - but how about `C = ReallyReallyLongClassName` and using `C.realpart` instead? And consider if it should be a class-level constant anyway... (Edit @AdniDog: You're missing the point. VB isn't the only language that does scoping different from Python, and the class name is just an - albeit not very well-chosen - example)

Comment: In any way, there's no use for shortening statements in Python. `C = WayTooLongClassName` is a solution, but I don't remember ever having used something like this in Python. I chose VB as an example by intention, because statements there can get very long.

Comment: Python has built-in support for complex numbers; you can just use `x = 0+0j`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want to do:

```
class Complex(object):
    def __init__(self, realpart=0, imagpart=0):
        self.realpart = realpart
        self.imagpart = imagpart
```

Accessing the member variables is the "self.realpart" call. What you were using is class attributes which are accessed like this:

```
Complex.some_attribute
```

Comment: hi, what's the use of object in Complex(object)?

Comment: It's what it inherits from. All new-style classes ultimately inherit from `object`. For example to make a `SuperComplex` class inheriting from `Complex`, you would write it as `class SuperComplex(Complex):`

Answer (score 0):

No. The data members you specified above are attributes of the class, and therefore require the class name to be specified. You could use `self.r = self.__class__.realpart` if you prefer. It seems as though you're just using these values as initializers though, so having `realpart` and `imagpart` at all is redundant.

(Also, note that Python has native support for complex numbers. Just write them such as 5+3j.)